# no such column: False When inserting into SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite

I have been banging my head against my desk for hours trying to get this to work, but I keep getting the same error,

`no such column: False: insert into USER (USER_USERNAME) values ('TEST');`

Here is my table creation code,

```
CREATE TABLE `USER` (
    `USER_ID`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `USER_USERNAME` TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Really simple code, but whenever I try inserting into it,

```
insert into USER (USER_USERNAME) values ('TEST');
```

It just returns that error ^

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your insert should be working.  Are you sure this error is reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was just being an idiot. Turns out a trigger was stopping me from inserting into the database and I didn't realise because it was one of my coworkers code